# How do you add docker-ce from OE to my Yocto Project?

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I'm just starting out with Yocto.  I've purchased the book (Mastering Embedded Linux Programming Third Edition) and waiting on its delivery.

In the meantime, I can't figure out how to add docker-ce to my project which is listed on layers.openembedded.org.

It always says:
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'docker-ce'

Thx.

Ian.

Comment: We can't really help you as this error can have many causes. Most likely, the layer providing docker-ce is not added correctly to the build. Did you add it in your confirmation/bblayers.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

The `docker-ce` recipe is provided by the [`meta-virtualization`](https://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-virtualization) layer. You should clone this layer next to your other layers, then check out the proper release branch (e.g. `kirkstone` if that's the release you are using). Then add the layer path to your `bbappend.conf` and you should be able to build `docker-ce` with `bitbake docker-ce`.